# set_preference does not work on FireFox profile

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, download

I have a python script which is trying to download an excel file automatically. I've tried to address firefox profile directly and it works fine:

```
path = '\\path\\to\\firefox\\default\\profile\\'
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('url') 
driver.find_element_by_id('downloadButton').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

But when I try to set a profile programmatically, it does not work; there is still download pop-up:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv/xls/xlsx')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('url') 
driver.find_element_by_id('downloadButton').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

I also changed the line `fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv/xls/xlsx')` to `fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('application/vnd.ms-excel'))`; but there was no changes.

Any idea what did I wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried

```
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream")
```

and

```
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

There is no changes in the results.

Answer (score 7):

According to [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) docs, `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` preference value should be a comma-separated list of MIME-types.

This one should work for you:

```
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream")
```

Demo (using [`XLSX Sample`](http://file-sample.com/xlsx) web page):

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "http://file-sample.com/xlsx/"

# configuring profile
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

# open the web page and download the file
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="post-entry"]//a').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

As the result, the file is downloaded in the current working directory.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi can you check what mime-type the file being downloaded has?

Comment: Its extension is `.xlsx`. It's a Microsoft Excel 2007 file. But I don't know how to check its mime-type from code. Could please help?

Comment: I have found the mime-type [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx) and added `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` to the list, but I got the same result.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi thank you, I've edited the answer with an example code that works for me - can you run it as is and see if the file is downloaded?

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi: [This page](http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/) may help you determine the right MIME type to use.

Comment: @unutbu thank you, should help the OP cause I still think this is something to do with the actual mime-type being not listed in the `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` preference.

Comment: @unutbu, command `curl -I file_url | grep Content-Type` gave me `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for the mime type of my file; the exact thing I've got from [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx).

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi: I'm stumped. If, when you run alecxe's code verbatim, that program succeeds but your actual code does not, then it seems to me we would need to see your actual code and be able to access the server to investigate further.

Comment: I have tried your answer with the URL you've provided and everything went fine; but this script still does not fit my problem. In my case, I have to login to a web-site, traverse through pages and somewhere in the middle of this, I click on a download button. This script does not work there. Any suggestion?

Comment: @unutbu, it's a local web-site. I can't give you access.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi: Maybe if you can copy the xlsx file to a different location on the local server you can experiment with how to download it more easily. You could also copy the xlsx file from http://file-sample.com/xlsx/ to the local server and see if alecxe's script works from there. The general idea is you can try setting up and running simpler experiments so that you may isolate the cause of the problem.

Comment: @unutbu, I cannot change the settings you've talked about. I'm trying to test a web-based software.

Comment: @alecxe I am trying same thing on Ubuntu with protractor but it always pops up download box. My file is linux executable and MIME-type is "application/x-executable". Could you please help?

Comment: @rohitkadam19 please post a separate question here on so providing all the necessary details. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Sure, Thanks! Asked new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247075/browser-helperapps-neverask-savetodisk-preference-isnt-working-with-protractor

Answer (score 0):

This work fine for me in Java, i think this gonna work in Python to.

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Users\\Administrateur\\Downloads\\");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```