# browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk preference isn't working with protractor for firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using firefox-profile with below settings -

```
var q = require('q');
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');

var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", process.cwd() +'/e2e/downloads/');
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-executable");
```

MIME-type of file is "application/x-executable". After adding all above details, it shows download pop up on firefox.

**Environment:-**

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Firefox 44
Protractor 3.2.2
Selenium-webdriver 2.53
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is just about specifying the correct mime-type. Apparently, just setting the `application/x-executable` not enough in this case.

The most reliable way to do that is to actually *open firefox manually*, download the file asking firefox to save the file automatically. Then, open Help - Troubleshooting Information, open Profile Folder, open `mimeTypes.rdf` file and locate the mime-types of the automatically downloaded files. You will have there something like:

```
<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:x-executable"
               NC:alwaysAsk="false"
               NC:useSystemDefault="true">
   <NC:externalApplication RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:externalApplication:x-executable"/>
</RDF:Description>
```

FYI, you can specify multiple mime-types in comma-separated string for the `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` preference.