# Keep Firefox from creating dialog boxes

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I currently have a script that will log on to my company's wiki, visit a page, and select a download to pdf option available on the page. However, when this option is chosen, this dialogue box

[image: dialogue]

I have read there is a way to create a Firefox profile that will suppress the creation of dialogue boxes, but I am unfamiliar with the library.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('https://company.wiki.com')
browser.find_by_id('login-link').click()
browser.fill('os_username', 'user')
browser.fill('os_password', 'pass')
browser.find_by_name('login').click()
browser.visit('https://pageoncompany.wiki.com')
browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/ul/li[4]').click()
browser.find_by_id('action-export-pdf-link').click()
```

Comment: Where did you that "there is a way to create a Firefox profile using node.js that will suppress the creation of dialogue boxes"?

Comment: I can't find the reference, so I ommitted node.js from the question, the problem still persists however.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible in python

Comment: Pretty sure it is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744294/set-preference-does-not-work-on-firefox-profile

Comment: This is all through selenium (with the first link you gave me: http://www.seleniumframework.com/python-intermediate/firefox-profile/). It also doesn't really prevent the dialog box

Comment: I am using selenium, and it does appear to achieve the end goal I am heading to.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Why is #selenium tagged here? I can see `splinter` in use. Am I missing something?

Comment: webdriver is the way I am looking to set preferences for my firefox profile. Webdriver operates through Selenium.
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: The issue is, as stated, that I need a way to set firefox preferences in my session so dialog boxes do not appear when I prompt a in web pdf download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set the preference in the Firefox Browser, then call my firefox profile

```
browser = Browser('firefox', profile=r'C:\Users\craab\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0lot9hun.default')
```